# Angular CLI : create a tar gz file with a version-based name after build

Tags: angular, jenkins, npm, angular-cli

All is in the title : **I would like to be able to generate a .tar.gz file after I've built my project, with a name depending on the version of my project**.

I tried npm pack, but all it does is taking the same name of the dist folder, and creates a tgz file. I need to create a tar.gz file for Jenkins (and we can't change Jenkins settings), depending on the version of my project.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I finally used a gulp task with both gulp-tar and gulp-gzip.

Answer (score 3):

`npm pack` should create your tar gz of your package with its name and version number if you run it at the same directory level as your package.json in the `dist/` directory